# Unable to hide div in mobile device on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this DIV:

```
<div class="column twelve wide" id="p1" style="text-align:left !important;">
...CONTENT...
</div>
```

Then I have this snippet to hide it:

```
$(function(){
        $('.bTest').click(function(){
            $('#p1').hide(function(){
                alert("complete");  
            });
        });
    });
```

When I click the Testbutton on the Desktop Version, it is completely fine, it hides the div and fires the alert when done.

On mobile (tested iPhone5 and Nexus 6) it hides the div. fires the alert and then SHOWS the div again?

Why is that and what am I missing?

//EDIT: This is the bTest class

```
<div class="ui green submit button bProceed bTest" data-type="m">TEST</div>
```

//Full markup (not sure what's relevant): http://pastebin.com/4mc8ziyX

Comment: WHERE is the bTest - perhaps it is overlapping whatever you want to click to show it again

Comment: try mouseup rather than click

Comment: What do you mean overlap? It is within the #p1 I am trying to hide... Putting it somewhere else does not change anything though...

Comment: So please show the complete actual relevant markup. How should we know it is inside?

Comment: It should work. Anyway, I recommend you to use also mobile events and improved jQuery method, something like `$('.bTest').on('click tap', function(){ //... });`

Comment: I expect relevant markup would be the RENDERED HTML of line 124 to 134 !!! - Please read http://sscce.org

Comment: Don't you have more JS functionality? `$('.bTest')` is the only element that takes an event? Maybe you are an overlap victim!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function () {
    $('#p1').click(function () {
        $('#p1').hide(function () {
            alert("complete");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That is only if he wants to click the div itself - not likely